# How to get ARN of AWS ParameterStore String in CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm deploying infra with AWS CDK Typescript and i already have a ParameterStore string stored, which i want to reference (the ARN) in an ECS Deployment as a secret

```
const apikey = ssm.fromStringParameterAttributes(this, 'api-key', {
            simpleName: false,
            parameterName: '/apikey',
        });
```

But i'm getting this error on every run :
Property 'fromStringParameterAttributes' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/builds/demo/projection/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ssm/index")'.

I checked the docs here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringListParameter.html
But as far as i can see it should be possible ?

Comment: `ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterAttributes(...` should eliminate the reported error.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to call is a member the `StringParameter` class as you can see from the docs you linked, so that's where you have to call it from:

```
const apikey = ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterAttributes(this, 'api-key', {
    simpleName: false,
    parameterName: '/apikey',
});
```